# $x^{(n)}$ converges to $x$ with respect to the discrete metric $d_{disc}$ iff there exists an $N\geq m$ such that $x^{(n)} = x$ for all $n\geq N$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $X$ be any set, and let $d_{disc}$ be the discrete metric on $X$. Let $(x^{(n)})_{n=m}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of points in $X$, and let $x$ be a point in $X$. Then $(x^{(n)})_{n=m}^{\infty}$ converges to $x$ with respect to the discrete metric $d_{disc}$ iff there exists an $N\geq m$ such that $x^{(n)} = x$ for all $n\geq N$.

**My solution**

According to the definition of convergence, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an $N\geq m$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq N \Rightarrow d(x^{(n)},x) \leq \varepsilon
\end{align*}
Consequently, if we choose $\varepsilon = 1/2$, we conclude there is an $N_{1/2}\geq m$ such that 
\begin{align*}
n\geq N_{1/2}\Rightarrow d(x^{(n)},x)\leq 1/2
\end{align*}

Since $d(a,b) = 1$ when $a\neq b$ and $d(a,b) = 0$ otherwise, we conclude that $d(x^{(n)},x) = 0$ for $n\geq N_{1/2}$.

In other words, $x^{(n)} = x$ for every $n\geq N_{1/2}$ as claimed, and the results follows.

Could someone please verify if is it correct?

Comment: What you have done  is perfect!

Comment: Yeah it's correct, you also need the reverse direction which is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!